# Using MySQL and Cassandra in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cassandra

I am using Codeigniter to develop my application. I am using MySQL database and I need to integrate Cassandra db in my site. So i need to use both of them in my framework.

I get the code from the following link for using [Codeigniter with Cassandra](https://github.com/zcourts/cassandraci), but I need to use both cassandra and mysql. Is it possible to use both? Half of the project is completed i am using MySQL.

I only need to integrate Cassandra, but the files downloaded from github the code is intergrated with cassandra. I can't find the steps or separate plugin cassandra files to integrate with Codeignitor.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible. [cassandraci](https://github.com/zcourts/cassandraci) is a library whose function you can access with

```
$this->db->query()->insert('key', array());
$r1 = $this->db->query()->get('key');
```

only if you autoload that db class. [Read more](http://crlog.info/2011/04/07/apache-cassandra-phpcassa-code-igniter-large-scale-php-app-in-5-minutes/)